# why the border in Photoshop turn out blurry?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, border

I'm using photoshop cs 6. when i try to make a border, it turn out blurry. I've check feather, and stroke. All set in 0px.

Here's the image of the border:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is trying to make a bezel effect.

Comment: hey there, thanks for answering. Can you tell me how to fix it? I'm a beginner in Photoshop. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Could you list the steps you took to achieve this? That way it will be easier to see what went wrong.

Comment: I use rectangular marquee tool, then select > border > border selection 10px. After that, edit > fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Making a border**

I can't check for certain now since I don't have PS where I am at the moment, but let me give you a few options.

**1) Shape**

1. Create a shape with the rectangular shape tool
2. In the layer palette, drag 'fill' to 0 (if you don't want a filled rectangle)
3. Go into the blending options for the shape and click on Stroke. Set it to 5 (for instance) and either inside/middle or outside. Whatever you prefer.

You should now have a shape with a border.

**2) Rasterized layer**

1. Create a new layer
2. Make a rectangular selection with the selection tool
3. Fill it with a color
4. Go to selection > modify selection > contract. Choose to contract with the amount of px you would like your border to have.
5. Now that your new selection is contracted, press backspace to delete the middle of your rectangle.

---

That's generally how you could make a border but as I said, I'm not sure if it's exactly correct (menus names etc.) since I don't have the program in front of me.

Comment: it works..thank you so much. you're a gem... sorry for the late reply. I was confused about which fill you referred to. Thanks again :)